# Determine whether the following maps $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ are linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Determine whether the following maps $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ are linear
>
> 1. $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1 · x_2$,
> 2. $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto (2 x_1, −x_2, x_1 + x_2)$,
> 3. $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto ⟨(α, β), (x_1, x_2)⟩$ for $α, β \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed.

Have a good sunday.

For example, I think 2 is one linear, but I'm undecided on how to display it. I am happy if you help me.

**Edit;**

1. $f(0) = 0$
2. $f(v_1 + v_2) = f(v_1) + f(v_2)$
3. $f(r \cdot v) = r \cdot f(v)$ with $v = (x_1, x_2)$

I thought it was, so what are you thinking about that?

Comment: 1. f(0)=0

2. ist f(v1+v2)=f(v1)+f(v2)

3. ist f(r*v)=r*f(v) mit v=(x1,x2)

Answer (score 0):

According with your edit you can prove that a map $f : X \rightarrow Y$, between two vector spaces $X$ and $Y$, is linear if it satisfies the following \begin{equation}
\label{1}
f(\alpha x + \beta y)= \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y), \forall x,y \in X, \forall \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{K},
\end{equation}where $\mathbb{K}$ is the scalar field. Notice that to prove that $f(0) = 0$ you can pick a scalar $\alpha = 0$.

From here you can calculate the left side and the right side of the previous equality and check if they coincide.

I will do the first, (i), and you can check the remaining 2.

So, take $x = (x_1,x_2), y = (y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and any $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{K}$. Then $$\alpha x + \beta y = (\alpha x_1+ \beta y_1,\alpha x_2+ \beta y_2)$$so that \begin{align*}
f(\alpha x + \beta y) & = f(\alpha x_1+ \beta y_1,\alpha x_2+ \beta y_2)\\
& = (\alpha x_1+ \beta y_1)(\alpha x_2+ \beta y_2)\\
& =\alpha^2x_1x_2 + \alpha \beta(x_1y_2+x_2y_1) + \beta^2y_1y_2.
\end{align*}Now we do the same for $\alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$.
\begin{align*}
 \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y) & = \alpha f(x_1,x_2) + \beta f(y_1,y_2)\\
 & = \alpha(x_1x_2) + \beta(y_1y_2)\\
& = \alpha x_1x_2 + \beta y_1y_2.
\end{align*}Now you can see that if $x = (1,1) = y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and for $\alpha = 1 = \beta \in \mathbb{K}$ we have $$f(\alpha x + \beta y) = 4 \neq 2 = \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y).$$Hence, this map is not linear.